# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex cannot be less than zero

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, networking, ftp

I have no idea why the following function works for the string ftp://ftp.hq.nasa.gov, but breaks on ftp://ftp.hq.nasa.gov/incoming

Just trying to get a list of the files in incoming and parse them accordingly.  There has to be something obvious I am missing.

I gave the line that it's breaking further down in the code. Posted the entire method, just in case.

```
    public string[] GetFileList()
    {
        string[] downloadFiles;
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
        try
        {
            reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp://" + ftpServerIP + "/"));
            reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
            reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
            reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            WebResponse response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            //MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd());
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                result.Append(line);
                result.Append("\n");
                line = reader.ReadLine();
            }
```

Breaks on the line below

```
            result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            //MessageBox.Show(response.StatusDescription);
            return result.ToString().Split('\n');
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            downloadFiles = null;
            return downloadFiles;
        }
    }
```

The error name is in the title: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex cannot be less than zero`

Comment: obviously `result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n')` returns -1, meaning there is no linebreak as you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the index before remove

```
int index  = result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n');
if(index  >=0)
{
  result.Remove(index, 1);
}
```